# How to use Drupal Commerce subscription products?

Tags: commerce

I created a site which has premium membership and want users to pay for those memberships.
I have installed [commerce_sp](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_sp) on my site but I don't know how to configure it and use it.

When a member pay for a membership for 1 year, for example:
Subscription validity: 2014-09-25 13:45:00

but I don't know why, when I check this member again every once in a while. the Subscription validity has changed to: 2015-09-24 13:45:00.

And I check this member again tomorrow,the Subscription validity has changed again:2017-09-22 13:45:00.

I don't know why the subscription validity change again and again.

I was very confused, anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have got issue with your rule set. Best way to use(configure) [commerce_sp](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_sp) or even [commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) product for membership is to put proper condition & then fire the event.

Simple Config :

- Create new products (using Subscription Products).
- Create product displays for those products.
- Go to Configuration>Rules.
- Find the Rule called "Subscription Started (update)" and clone it.
- Rename the cloned rule.
- Make the Event "Completing the Checkout Process". Add some more like "user of type" etc.
- Make the Elements "Order contains a particular product" and specify the SKUs of your subscription products.
- For Actions, use "rule set: Subscription start" with parameter as "User:[commerce-order:owner] and "Schedule component evaluation" as is and added "Add user role" with Parameter: User:[commerce-order:owner] and Roles: my subscriber role.
- Set the low weight for this rule set.

You can modify rule as per your requirement & it will work accordingly.

Comment: I just want to Subscription started after condition is "Waiting for the buyer to confirm"

so I changed the rule's conditions:
rule:Apply bought subscription time
conditions:Waiting for the buyer to confirm
actions:
loop   Parameter: list: [commerce-order:commerce...
rule: Line item is subscription product


and after I change this rule, the subscription validity change again and again.
what's wrong?
and how to change the Subscription started after condition is "Waiting for the buyer to confirm"?